# Can I iterate over URL's to find images?

Tags: google-chrome, filesystems, url

I have 52 files to retrieve and download, however, I've started manually entering the web URL. I was curious as to if I could find all the files in the webserver and simply download them, or iterate over URL's and open them all.

The URL is formatted as follows:

http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/a/a_gs_1.jpg

Where 'a' is the letter of the alphabet and the number being capitalised or not.

For example:

/english_alphabet/c/c_gs_1.jpg
Would be a capital 'C'

/english_alphabet/d/d_gs_2.jpg
Would be a lowercase 'd'

I hope this gets my point across.

Rather than manually entering them like this I'd like to either sprawl through the webserver for these files or iterate through the combinations and then open the tabs. Any ideas? It would be a time saver rather than manually entering 52 URL's :p Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Linux with bash, or under Windows with [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) or with the [native bash shell running on windows](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DevelopersCanRunBashShellAndUsermodeUbuntuLinuxBinariesOnWindows10.aspx), you can use the [bash expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html).

For example writing `echo {a..z}` your shell will expand it in

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
```

So you can iterate with a for cycle and download each single url generated. Here below a script example and after a one line command.

```
BaseUrl="http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails"
for i in {a..z}
 do 
  # here below for each $i it will see a, b, c ... z
  wget ${BaseUrl}/english_alphabet/${i}/${i}_gs_1.jpg
 done
```

Note: I store the URL in the variable BaseUrl to keep the script above more easy to read.

In one line you can write directly

```
for i in {a..z}  ; do wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/${i}/${i}_gs_1.jpg  ; done
```

**Note:**

- I assume you have the right to download from that site (you have always to check for the copyright of the each site).
- You can always use `wget` to download the whole subdirectory limiting the download to the jpg files with a specified *key* in the name. Check for the help and capability of [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/).

Under powershell you can write a script similar to the above one, with the respective syntax.

Comment: Never had wget and was confused at first! Handy little tool, thanks. And yes, with my limited understanding of copyright, I believe they are okay considering they're up for free download on their website for example: http://www.loopsandtails.com/practice-alphabet/cursive-handwriting-practice/b/#guidesheets-tab

Comment: Also, I'm confused what the '-1' means on my question? Is that a bad thing?

Comment: @T.Hep Usually for private use you can download all that you can see. If they do not want that you use a robot/spider (a tool) they may write a little file (robot.txt) that the robots _should_ read before downloading... About the `-1`: give it a look to [ask] page. Usually you should show some attempts/ effort to avoid to finish in the category _"script request"_. If someone believe that or that the question is bad made well it can arrive a `-1` or a comment. it is possible to change it later if you modify your post. Give a look to [why-vote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) page too...

Answer (score 1):

Its probably fewer keystrokes just to brute force edit it in a text editor with cut and paste to make a script than do it programmatically

```
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/a/a_gs_1.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/b/b_gs_1.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/c/c_gs_1.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/d/d_gs_1.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/e/e_gs_1.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/f/f_gs_1.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/g/g_gs_1.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/h/h_gs_1.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/i/i_gs_1.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/j/j_gs_1.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/k/k_gs_1.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/l/l_gs_1.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/m/m_gs_1.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/n/n_gs_1.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/o/o_gs_1.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/p/p_gs_1.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/q/q_gs_1.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/r/r_gs_1.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/s/s_gs_1.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/t/t_gs_1.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/u/u_gs_1.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/v/v_gs_1.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/w/w_gs_1.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/x/x_gs_1.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/y/y_gs_1.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/z/z_gs_1.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/a/a_gs_2.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/b/b_gs_2.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/c/c_gs_2.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/d/d_gs_2.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/e/e_gs_2.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/f/f_gs_2.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/g/g_gs_2.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/h/h_gs_2.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/i/i_gs_2.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/j/j_gs_2.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/k/k_gs_2.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/l/l_gs_2.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/m/m_gs_2.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/n/n_gs_2.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/o/o_gs_2.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/p/p_gs_2.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/q/q_gs_2.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/r/r_gs_2.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/s/s_gs_2.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/t/t_gs_2.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/u/u_gs_2.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/v/v_gs_2.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/w/w_gs_2.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/x/x_gs_2.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/y/y_gs_2.jpg
wget http://www.loopsandtails.com/wp-content/themes/LoopsAndTails/english_alphabet/z/z_gs_2.jpg
```

Comment: In (ba)sh it is oneliner `for c in {a..z}; do for n in 1 2; do wget ".../$c/${c}_gs_$n.jpg"; done; done`.